# Handling many ofstream operations at once

Tags: c++, multithreading, stream, wav

I would like to ask for advice. As I am not very experienced user of C++. I lack a bit knowledge about threads - but I've been doing a lot in Android so I know the general idea.

I need to write 8 *.wav files at once. I have a callback called very often with upcoming signal from 8 input channels. I need to save data to *.wav from each channel (recording). This require me to open file every time I get new data and write additional 256 samples of data at the end of it.

Doing so with 2 inputs is fine, but after 3 or more my input latency is starting to increase. Processor is lagging so probably I have to do it in some kind of thread.

I think it should be quite common problem but I haven't learn yet how to handle it. Can someone explain me right way to do it? Is it necessary to use it http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/ or are there any other simple/elegant patterns.

Comment: Do you mean writing to 8 files in parallel (concurrently)?  You will need a specialized hardware architecture to do this.

Comment: Well yes. I need to record data to 8 different files (one per channel) at once.

Comment: Embedded systems poll each channel, serially, in sequence, and storing the data in a circular queue.  Another task pulls data out of the queue and processes it.  Most likely, the processor can poll the data inputs faster than you need.  If you need faster, you will to change the H/W architecture (use DMA channels).

Comment: Thanks for giving various ideas. I am going to read about it a little now and see how far I need to go with it to get satisfying effect. For now I will see what will happen if I extend buffer size.

Comment: Don't reopen the files every time you get data. Open the files once, write data as much as you need, then close them. Opening a file is slow; writing is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to record, or save, the data from 8 input channels.
I highly recommend at least 8 large buffers to contain the data.

When there is a pause in the input or in the background, you can write the data to the files.  Wait for a large amount of data to collect before writing the buffers to the files.  The file I/O loves to process large blocks of data rather than many small ones.  You can always flush the output streams which tells the OS to write to the file.

If you want to play with threads, I recommend at least three.
Thread 1 -- read input channels and store in buffers.
Thread 2 -- GUI
Thread 3 -- Writes buffers to files.

Remember that thread 1 is the highest priority.  When it sees a low amount of space remaining in the buffer, it should wake up thread 3 to write out the buffers to the files.

You should maintain at least 2 buffers for each input channel.  This is called double buffering and allows thread 3 to write the buffer to file while thread 1 is reading the input channel data into another buffer.

Comment: Seems like for now just increasing buffer size 16x is enough in my environment to record 8 channels at once. It doesn't affect my input latency at all. Maybe in future threads will be needed but for now it suffice. Thanks.